# Sending a request with Windows Authentication from ASP.NET service

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, httprequest, windows-authentication

I have a working Python script which sends a request to an web service using Windows Authentication in order to get a token.

The bit that I'm trying to replicate is:

```
url = 'https://ssologin.company.com/Logon/Logon.aspx?permission=permission'
h = WC.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
h.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
h.SetOption(6, False)
h.Open('GET', url, False)
h.Send()
```

I have an ASP.NET Core service which tries to do it this way:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://ssologin.company.com/Logon/Logon.aspx?permission=permission");
WinHttpHandler handler = new WinHttpHandler();
handler.ServerCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;           
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Right now I am getting the following error:
WinHttpException: Error 12029 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A connection with the server could not be established'.

However, if I comment `// handler.ServerCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;`, then I get Error 401 Unauthorised. I also noticed that CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials is NULL.

Can you please let me know what I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: are you required to use the WinHttpHandler, you can use the default System.Net.HttpClientHandler whit handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true, which will pass the the Windows token for the authentication.

Comment: @spzvtbg No, I am not required, I just thought it will be a closer match to what the python code is doing. As you said, I switched it to HttpClientHandler with .UseDefaultCredentials = true, but now I got this error: SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: check the url maybe you have one /Logon more or the service is unavailable on the server side

Comment: consider testing the request in postman, from there you can get and the  source code for the request in bunch of languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the authentication worked fine, but the request was redirecting to a service which refuses to connect. The easy fix to this was to just disable redirecting. Also, at @spzvtbg's suggestion, I used the default `HttpClienthandler`.

The final code ended up like this:

```
var uri = new Uri("https://ssologin.company.com/Logon/Logon.aspx?permission=permission");
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```